# Automated Manual Testing / Robot-computer interaction

Tags: software, artificial-intelligence, automation

What is the technical term for a computer mechanically interfaces another computer? For example a robot mechanically interacting (vs API) with a PC or smartphone as a human would to automatically gather data and making input decisions based on feedback from the device

At a software level, it can be like Selenium Webdriver simulating clicks on a web page.

[image]

Possible use cases are

- Quick and dirty way to interface with a proprietary mobile app system to achieve automation interoperability without reverse engineering APIs
- Software Testing Cases

I wish to do more research into this. Is there an off the shelf prototype that is available for purchase? Or some schematic that would allow you to device your own, complete with open source APIs? One that fits many device types and brands?

Comment: the first thing that pops into my head is a `touchpanel test jig`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an off the shelf prototype that is available for purchase?

Generally, of the shelf robots, there are plenty, specifically for UI testing there are none

> Or some schematic that would allow you to device your own, complete with open source APIs?

Generally schematics/APIs for robots, there are plenty. Specifically for UI testing there are none